# Action script3 trace in flex builder hierarchy output

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, trace

i am using Flex builder 4.5 and my problem is this that this code doos not work, when i used trace(event.target) i get following in result in console,

```
deleteme.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.VGroup5.button1
```

And if i replace this long line in 'if' statement code works.(deleteme is the project name). Dont you think it should only say button1 instead of this all long line with all hierarchy , if that is the case then how we can shortend it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
           initialize="handleClick(event)">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function init():void{
            button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
        }
        private function handleClick(event:Event):void{
            trace(event.target);
            if(event.target == "button1"){
                button1.label = "Button 1 clicked";
            }else if(event.target == "button2"){
                button2.label = "Button 2 clicked";
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:VGroup width="100%">
    <s:Button id="button1" label="Button 1" click="handleClick(event)"/>
    <s:Button id="button2" label="Button 2" />
</s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

thanks in advance,

(i tried with sdk 4.1 still same answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
           initialize="handleClick(event)">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function init():void{
            button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
        }
        private function handleClick(event:Event):void{
            trace(event.target);
            if(event.currentTarget == button1){
                button1.label = "Button 1 clicked";
            }else if(event.currentTarget == button2){
                button2.label = "Button 2 clicked";
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:VGroup width="100%">
    <s:Button id="button1" label="Button 1" click="handleClick(event)"/>
    <s:Button id="button2" label="Button 2" />
</s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

It has no sense to compare visual objects with strings. Compare objects with objects themselves.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, i am still getting same output form the trace statement. i copy paste your code to see if i am missing something but 'currentTarget' does not help. did it worked in your ide?

Comment: What exactly do you expect from trace and for what purpose?

Comment: trace should give out button1 or button2  rather than giving that long info. but now button 1 works though.

Comment: Ok, try to use `trace(event.target.id)`? But I still can't understand your strict requirements to tracing and telling your application doesn't work because of trace formatting. Trace is just debug info for temporary purposes and should be removed after finishing debug session. What is purpose of trace in your case? Just curious :)

Comment: my code suppose to change the label of clicked button but nothing was happening so i am using 'trace' to see what event was producing as my 'if' statment was not running. since i was getting long statement in the trace statement which is not going to match the 'if' so i trying to find out how to get id of the object. trace(event.target.id) did charm, thanks again

Comment: If you look at my code I've fixed your problem with if statement.